# How to explain “free” command output?

Tags: linux

On my Linux VM, free shows:

```
$ free -l
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        8174808      868688      141352       14804     7164768     6861684
Low:        8174808     8033456      141352
High:             0           0           0
Swap:       1998844      165604     1833240
```

As my understanding, High memory is user space memory, why it's 0? Also, why `Mem used` is 868688 but `Low used` is 8033456?